# InnoDb transactions with create statements

Tags: mysql, transactions, innodb

Are sql statements such as CREATE TABLE `tbl_name` ..... allowed in transactions.

For example:

```
begin;

CREATE TABLE .......;

sdfghjk;

rollback;
```

The table is still created despite a statement in the transaction failing, and a rollback at the end.  Is there a way to prevent the table from being created if a statement in the transaction fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DDL statements are allowed within transactions, but are not generally impacted by the transactions.  From the MySQL Documentation on what can and cannot be rolled back:

> Some statements cannot be rolled back. In general, these include data
>   definition language (DDL) statements, such as those that create or
>   drop databases, those that create, drop, or alter tables or stored
>   routines.
>
> You should design your transactions not to include such statements. If
>   you issue a statement early in a transaction that cannot be rolled
>   back, and then another statement later fails, the full effect of the
>   transaction cannot be rolled back in such cases by issuing a ROLLBACK
>   statement.

[Source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cannot-roll-back.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you still need to use table you can do [`create temporary table....`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html). It doesn't commit transaction but will be deleted when connection will be closed.